# Disable access to the DB via Windows Authentication, and disable SQL Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am deploying my application (including a database) for a client.

What I need is to install SQL Server 2008 (without  SQL Management Studio) so that only I can access the db using my laptop.

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this link](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/06/12/sql-server-2008-step-by-step-installation-guide-with-images/) is provides a full tutorial for steps on how to install MSSQL Server 2008. On the step that shows you this image just unselect the checkbox:

> Management Tools - Basic

[image: this image]

Answer (score 0):

Unclick the Management Tools checkbox in the SQL Server installer.

That won't stop them accessing the database via Windows authentication, nor for that matter, does it preclude them from installing Management Studio later.